# Set opened state to inactive for bundle items tab in product edit page magento 2

Tags: admin, magento2.2.2, bundled-product, tabs

How can I set opened state to inactive for bundle items tab in product edit page Magento 2 so that the tab is loaded only on click, not on page load. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947465/how-to-close-all-accordions-in-magento2-admin-product-detail-by-default

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to Overriding ( as described below ) the class 
***Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePane*** for your requirement.

I assume you will create a custom module name "**Vendor_Module**" to do this customization tasks

**step 1)** Create **di.xml** under

***/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/***

File : **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" 
                type="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" />
</config>
```

**step 2:** Create **BundlePanel.php** under

***/app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/***

File : **BundlePanel.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class BundlePanel extends \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel
{


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = parent::modifyMeta($meta);
        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CODE_BUNDLE_DATA, $meta, null, 'children');
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $path,
            $meta,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataScope' => '',
                            'opened' => false,
                            'sortOrder' => $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                                $meta,
                                static::GROUP_CONTENT,
                                static::SORT_ORDER
                            )
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
           );
        return $meta;
    }


}
```

**step 3:** Run di compile  commnad

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

**step 4:** clean your Magento cache

========================================================

**Please Note:**

To **Show/hide** the Bundle Items tab, Please change **$meta** array key value to **true**/**false** in the Overriding class file **Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel.php** as follows :

'**opened**' => **false**,

========================================================

Comment: You answer is correct but it didn't solve my problem. Can you please have a look:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255807/magento-2-admin-taking-too-much-to-open-product-edit-page-for-large-number-of-as

Comment: Yes. I Will take a look on another issue you mentioned. Thank you.