# Magento 2 admin taking too much to open product edit page for large number of assciated products

Tags: magento2, admin, bundle, associate-products, product-edit-page

Magento 2 admin product edit page taking too much time to load product edit page for a large number of the associated product(around 1500) for bundle products.

Till now, I have tried to set `'opened' =>false` in Ui component. But this doesn't solve the problem the problem of time it took to load the page. How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is a server issue. try checking your php resource settings
check those settings like **max_execution_time** and the **max_input_time** 
try to change it and restart your server after

Then check if it resolves the issue.

Comment: No, it's not an issue of max_execution_time or time as the page loads completely after around 3 mins.